# Indefinite Article for "s-t-path"

Tags: indefinite-articles, mathematics

I am currently writing a (mathematical) paper, which considers so called paths in graphs.
The start of a path is usually denoted by the letter s and the end of the path is denoted by t.
The whole path is then called "s-t-path" and my question is about which indefinite article to use with it.

The selected answer in [Indefinite article before symbols](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107060/indefinite-article-before-symbols) says to just use 'a' or 'an' according to how you pronounce what follows.
This would imply that one should write "a s-t-path", because the s goes with a (a superhero, etc.). When I am actually using the construct in a spoken sentence, however, what I would be saying is "an s-t-path".

There are 39,700 google search results for "an s-t-path" versus 41,900 results for "a s-t-path", which is to show that this topic truly divides the nation ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> to just use 'a' or 'an' according to how you **pronounce** what follows.

Yes.

> This would imply that one should write "a s-t-path"

**No**, it wouldn't. As you mention yourself, you **pronounce** the S of s-t-path starting with a vowel sound.

So how you figure that it would imply you would write "a s-t-path" is beyond me. I would certainly advise to write "an s-t-path", the same conclusion you would have gotten to if you would not have read over the word *pronounced* in the advice you took from the other question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
Your passive aggressive style of writing makes it a pleasure to read :)

Comment: Not sure if that's a compliment, but I'll take it as one :) Sorry if I seemed a bit harsh :)